# Assigning functions to dynamic movieclips in a loop, ActionScript 2

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have done this same thing in ActionScript 3, but am not familiar with ActionScript 2, which I am forced to use for this project. I am loading products into a SWF via XML and attempting to add a click event to each dynamically-created movieclip. Simply tracing the text from a node in XML will do for now. I'd like to assign a property called "desc" or "description" to each movieclip and have it trace that property's value when clicked. Here is the relevant portion of my code as it stands:

```
    var iXML:XML = new XML();
    iXML.ignoreWhite = true;
    iXML.onLoad = init;
    iXML.load("http://localhost:8888/products.php?p=Shortboards");



function init():Void 
{
    var imgNum:Number = iXML.firstChild.childNodes.length;
    var holder_mc:MovieClip = slider.createEmptyMovieClip("holder_mc", slider.getNextHighestDepth());

    for (var i:Number = 0; i < imgNum; i++) 
    {
        var ob:Object = new Object();
        ob.id = i;
        ob.mc = holder_mc.createEmptyMovieClip("img" + ob.id + "_mc", holder_mc.getNextHighestDepth());
        ob.mc._x = (137 * ob.id);
        ob.mc.loadMovie(iXML.firstChild.childNodes[i].attributes.src);
    }

    for(var i in holder_mc){
    trace('key: ' + i + ', value: ' + holder_mc[i]);
    holder_mc[i].description = (iXML.firstChild.childNodes[i].attributes.desc);
    holder_mc[i].onRelease = function() {
        trace (this.description);
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var iXML:XML = new XML(); 
iXML.ignoreWhite = true;  
iXML.onLoad = init; 
iXML.load("http://localhost:8888/products.php?p=Shortboards"); 
function init():Void {      
    var imgNum:Number = iXML.firstChild.childNodes.length;      
    var holder_mc:MovieClip = slider.createEmptyMovieClip("holder_mc", slider.getNextHighestDepth());      
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < imgNum; i++)     {         
        var ob:Object = new Object();         
        ob.id = i;          
        ob.mc = holder_mc.createEmptyMovieClip("img" + ob.id + "_mc", holder_mc.getNextHighestDepth()); 
        ob.img = ob.mc.createEmptyMovieClip("img_mc", 1); 
        ob.mc._x = (137 * ob.id);          
        ob.img.loadMovie(iXML.firstChild.childNodes[i].attributes.src);     
    } 
    var x:Number = 0;        
        for(var i in holder_mc){         
            trace('key: ' + i + ', value: ' + holder_mc[i]);         
            holder_mc[i].description = (iXML.firstChild.childNodes[x++].attributes.desc);          
            holder_mc[i].onRelease = function() {              
                trace (this.description);        
            } 
        } 
}
```